# Pandas remove NaN and move all value on the same line

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple list that want to convert it to excel using pandas.
I googled about how to remove NaN, but they all talk about remove either whole row or column.
Is there a way to put all the value on the same line?

```
list = [{'cisco': 15}, {'developer': 15}, {'root': 15}]
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

The output is like this
cisco  developer  root
0   15.0        NaN   NaN
1    NaN       15.0   NaN
2    NaN        NaN  15.0

But I would like to have it look like this
cisco  developer  root
0   15.0       15.0   15.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change format, you can use:

```
l = [{'cisco': 15}, {'developer': 15}, {'root': 15}]

print ({k: v for x in l for k, v in x.items()})
{'cisco': 15, 'developer': 15, 'root': 15}

df = pd.DataFrame([{k: v for x in l for k, v in x.items()}])
#if one element dicts
df = pd.DataFrame([{list(x.keys())[0]: list(x.values())[0] for x in l}])

print (df)
   cisco  developer  root
0     15         15    15
```

If already missing values in DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l)

df = df.stack().droplevel(0).to_frame().T
print (df)
   cisco  developer  root
0   15.0       15.0  15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the values as a list, Below format works

df_list = {'cisco': [15], 'developer': [15], 'root': [15]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_list)

Answer (score 0):

Python has a tool to merge dictionaries: `ChainMap`:

```
from collections import ChainMap

lst = [{'cisco': 15}, {'developer': 15}, {'root': 15}]

df = pd.DataFrame([ChainMap(*lst)])
```

Output:

```
   cisco  developer  root
0     15         15    15
```